# Can't change innerHTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do something very simple with some js and I am trying to make a somewhat loading thingy by showing an ellipsis in the output element before showing the answer. The second change to innerHTML is working and the program is sleeping, but it won't change initially. Help?

```js
function getRandom() {

  function sleep(milliseconds) {
    console.log("go");
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
  }

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "...";
  sleep(1000);


  let inputRaw = document.getElementById("typeField").value;
  let inputLines = inputRaw.split('\n');

  var randomInputLine = inputLines[Math.floor(Math.random() * inputLines.length)]

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = randomInputLine;
  console.log("click");
}
```

```css
#row1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#row2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#typeField {
  border: 5px solid gray;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

#output {}

#getRandomButton {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 1px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">
  <textarea rows="20" cols="60" id="typeField">
            Enter list of words to randomly choose from, each on its own line
                </textarea>
  <br>
  <h1 id="output"></h1>
</div>
<div id="row2">
  <button onclick="getRandom()" id="getRandomButton">Get Random</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The `sleep` function is harmful to the user due to the abuse it puts the processor through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loop is keeping JavaScript busy, and so there is no opportunity for the DOM to update. Any change you make to `innerHTML` only becomes visible when JavaScript stops executing your code. So as long as you loop, this is not happening. Be aware that such a "busy loop" is also blocking the user interaction: no click or key press on the web page can be processed while that loop is continuing.

Instead use `setTimeout`.

```
function getRandom() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "...";
  console.log("click");

  setTimeout(function () { 
    let inputRaw = document.getElementById("typeField").value;
    let inputLines = inputRaw.split('\n');

    var randomInputLine = inputLines[Math.floor(Math.random() * inputLines.length)]

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = randomInputLine;
  }, 1000);
}
```

`setTimeout` will schedule some JavaScript to be executed some time later. But before that timeout expires, there is no more JavaScript executing, and so the page can update with whatever changes you made to `innerHTML` (and possibly other changes to the DOM).

More on this aspect of JavaScript: [Concurrency model and the event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).